# Do pickled sausages need to be refrigerated?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, sausages, convenience-foods

We have a jar of Hannah's Red Hot Pickled Sausages that we just opened last night.  I couldn't find any "Refrigerate After Opening" indication anywhere on the jar, so we left them out overnight.  I'm still uneasy about it, but the only way to ask Hannah's is to have a facebook account.  I don't have one since I don't use facebook (yes, only person on the planet), so I was hoping you may know for sure.

Answer (score 7):

I have a jar of "Big John's" pickled sausages and right on the bottom it says "NEVER NEEDS REFRIGERATION"!  They sit at stores and bars for for many days if not weeks and are sold by the sausage.

I found this on Hannah's Facebook page.  "They do not need to be refrigerated after opening in temperatures below 75 degrees. Recommended refrigeration for temps higher."

Answer (score 4):

I'm unfamiliar with Hannah's, but if they are pickled with vinegar you might be okay so long as you consume them within a few days.  If it were dilly beans or gherkins I'd say you're probably fine (depending on the amount of vinegar) - but meat is a different matter.

Do they look anything like [this](http://www.wisconsinmade.com/gift-ideas/Hot-Pickled-Polish-Sausage-4051.aspx) (or have similar ingredients)?

Answer (score 1):

When I was a kid, 1950's our local market had jars of everything pickled, pigs feet, sausages of different kinds, eggs, cheeses and other stuff from what Big Mike said was from the home land momma makes. None of it was ever refrigerated for months or more and I and many others ate it often.  The key word is pickled, meaning preserved beyond spoiling.